# Is it sensible to have a table that does not reference any other in a database design?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

I'd like to get some advice on database design. Specifically, consider the following (hypothetical) scenario:

- **Employees** - table holding all employee details
- **Users** - table holding employees that have username and password to access software
- **UserLog** - table to track when users login and logout and calculate 
  time on software

[image]

In this scenario, if an employee leaves the company I also want to make sure I delete them from the `Users` table so that they can no longer access the software. I can achieve this using `ON DELETE CASCADE` as part of the FK relationship between `EmployeeID` in `Employees` and `Users`.

However, I don't want to delete their details from the `UserLog` as I am interested in collating data on how long people spend on the software and the fact that they no longer work at the company does not mean their user behaviour is no longer relevant.

What I am left with is a table `UserLog` that has no relationships with any other tables in my database. **Is this a sensible idea?**

Having looked through books etc / googled online I haven't come across any DB schemas with tables that have no relationships with others and so my gut instinct here is saying that my approach is not robust...

I'd appreciate some guidance please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal preference in this case would be to "soft delete" an employee by adding a "DeletedDate" column to the Employees table. This will allow you to maintain referential integrity with your UserLog table and all details for all employees, past and present, remain available in the database.

The downside to this approach is that you need to add application logic to check for active employees.

Comment: Or you can create a view for active employees and use that instead of the base table in your application.

Comment: Interesting idea. In this case, for a large organisation wouldn't I end up with a lot of redundant data in my DB i.e. if company has high staff turnover I will end up holding a lot of data that is no longer relevant and over time would degrade performance?

Comment: @Remnant: One of the guiding principles I work by is: "Don't assume performance problems before you have them." If it does indeed become a problem in the future, you have options: you could, as @HLGEM suggested, create a materialized view of active employees, you could look into table partitioning so that the active/inactive employees are separated, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and further responses. I will adopt your approach as I now see the merit in that. Also, seems that most other replies are saying same as you so feels like clear indication that this is best way forward

Comment: I use an "IsDeleted" bit to do this so I agree with Joe. I wouldn't necessarily worry about "redundant" data or simply having too much; as Joe says - Don't assume performance problems before you have them.  However, there is another class of problems that may support deleting auxiliary data (e.g. data in other tables that use the employees table's PK as a foreign key).  In my system, we often query these tables for aggregate data and we don't want deleted members' data. Nor do we want the overhead of always checking the IsDeleted status. Thus, we do delete records from referencing tables.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly sensible.  The log is just a raw audit of data that should never change.  It doesn't need to be normalized (and shouldn't be) and/or linked to other tables.

Ideally, I would put write-heavy audit logging in a different database entirely than the read-heavy transactional day-to-day stuff.  They may grow differently over time.  But starting small it's fine to keep them in the same database as long as you understand the fundamental differences between them.

On a side note, I would recommend not deleting the users from the tables.  Maybe have some kind of IsActive or IsDeleted bit on them that would effectively blind them from the application, but deleting should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Thanks. On your final paragraph, why do you say deleting should be avoided?

Comment: @Remnant: On the technical side it's a costly table operation, possibly forcing index-rebuilds and such.  But more importantly on a business data side it gets rid of information.  Maybe copy it to some kind of archive data store before deleting?  In a highly normalized structure it would require deleting everything linked to that user as well, or at least re-assigning to a dummy user, either of which may be undesirable.  Ultimately, data retention is a business logic decision.  But favor a decision that can be later changed over one that can't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have here is that it's perfectly possible to insert UserLog data for users that have never existed as there's no link to the table that defines valid users.

I would say that perhaps the better course of action would be to mark the users as invalid and remove *all* their personal details when they leave rather than delete the record entirely.

That's not to say there aren't situations where it is valid to have a table (or tables) on the database that don't reference others.

Comment: @Remnant, I don't think there is a problem with your design, but Dave's suggestion for this particular case is a good one.  You can add a delete trigger that cancels the delete and does an update to remove the personal data and mark them as invalid as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a sensible idea

The problem is this.  Since the data isn't linked you can delete something from the employee table and still have references in the UserLog.  After the employee infomration is deleted, you have no way of knowing what Log data ties back to. Is this ok? Technically yes.  There is nothing preventing you from doing it, but then why are you keeping the data in the first place? You also have no guarantee that the data in the table actually is about an employee. Someone could accidently enter a wrong EmployeeID in the table that doesn't belong to anyone.  Keys help prevent data corruption.  It's always better to have extra data than it is to have bad data.

What I've found is that you never want to delete data when possible.  Space is cheap, and you can add flags etc. to show the record isn't active.  Yes, this does cause more work (this can be quickly remedied by creating a view which only shows active employees), and saying that you should never delete data is far fetched, but you start linking data together.  Deleting becomes very difficult.  If you are not adding a FK just so you can delete records, it's a tell tale sign you need to rethink your strategy.

Relying on Cascade Delete can be very dangerous too.  The model you are stating is that anytime you don't want data deleted you have to know not to add a FK to that table which links it back to users.  It doesn't take long for someone to forget this.

Comment: (+1) - I am intrigued as most repsonses seem to be unanimous that deleting should be avoided. Other than the 'space is cheap' argument, why is that? To play devil's advocate, surely deleting records is as fundamental as updating and inserting...?

Comment: From a technical view you're right.  The problem I've found is that a lot of data becomes "intertwined" and what I mean is that this A links to B and B links to C and so on.  Data has value.  Companies use it to make decisions about how to function.  At times there is a legal need to have the data.  The list goes on. Outside of having an archival system, when you delete data you are asserting that the existing data rely on what's deleted and that you never need what you are getting rid of.  The amount of time and money it takes to save and work around is miniscule compared to not having it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use logical deletion or disabling a user by adding a bool value Deleted or Disabled to the Users table.

Or replace the EmployeeId with the name of the employee in the UserLog.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using the soft delete process, is to store all the historical details you would want about the user at the time the log record is created rather than store the employee id. So you might have username, logintime, logouttime, sessionlength in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Sensible? Sure, as in it makes sense as you've described your need to keep those users indefinitely. The problem you'll run into is maintaining the tables. Instead of doing a cascading update once, you'll have to use at least two updates in order to insert a new user.

Answer (score 0):

I think a table as you are suggesting is perfectly fine.  I frequently encounter log tables that are do not have explicit relationships with other tables.  Just because a database is "relational" doesn't mean everything has to relate haha.

One thing that I do notice though is that you are using `EmployeeID` in the log, but not using it as a foreign key to your `Employee` table.  I understand why you don't want that, since you will be dropping employees.  But, if you are dropping them completely, then the `EmployeeID` column is meaningless.

A solution to this would be to keep a flag for employees, such as `active`, that tracks if they are active or not.  That way, the log data is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

IANADBA but it's generally considered very bad practice indeed to delete almost anything from a DB ever,It would be far better here to have some kind of locked flag / "deleted" datestamp on your users table and preserve your FK.